# First item in tab-content not working Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I made a list group of categories that when clicked will display the available subcategories for their respective categories however, the 1st item in foreach for the subcategory is not working but the rest is working fine. Here is my code.

list-group-item

```
<div id="subcategory-tabs">
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush" id="subcategory-list-tab" role="tablist">
        @foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action subcategory-tab-link {{ request()->is('/c/'.$subcategory->slug) ? 'active' : '' }}" href='#tab-{{ $subcategory->slug }}' data-toggle="list" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-{{ $subcategory->slug }}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

tab-content

```
<div class="tab-content" id="categorized-tab-content">
    @foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory)
        <div class="tab-pane fade in show {{ request()->is('/c/'.$subcategory->slug) ? 'active' : '' }}" role="tabpanel" id="tab-{{ $subcategory->slug }}" aria-labelled-by="tab-{{ $subcategory->slug }}">
            @if ($subcategory->slug == $subcategory->slug)
                {{ $subcategory->name }}
            @endif
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

When I click the very 1st subcategory, its tab-content isn't showing anything, it doesnt even change its class to active.

Answer (score 0):

redefine your class like this
`class="tab-pane fade in show '.{{ request()->is('/c/'.$subcategory->slug) ? 'active' : '' }}'"`